# setting up symfony ubuntu on virtual machine from mac

Tags: symfony, virtual-machine

Is it possible to run Symfony dev on a virtual machine?

In the config.php it queries the request uri, if not 127.0.0.1 in errors and says it can only be configured on localhost.

How do i get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason for that - `config` and `app_dev` are private resources and should only be ran from localhost.

Since you want to run your `dev` from VM Host (rather than VM Guest) you should just add your interface address to both `config.php` and `app_dev.php`.

For example, I have set up VMWare which allocated the address `192.168.78.10` to my VM Guest. My VM Host is at `192.168.78.1` (first address in that network). So you need to add `198.168.78.1` to both of those files.

Comment: ie adding to the array of allowed ip's for the dev environment?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can comment out the line judging the IP (127.0.0.1) in app_dev.php.

Sometimes it is worthy to do so especially when everything is fine in the local env but fails in the actual prod env.